# Wordpress Password Issues

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress site in a cloud 9 dev environment and something strange has happened with passwords. None of my passwords for WP Users are working, even though I have copied them directly from MYSQL tables. The forgot password page was also re-directing to a piece of HTML from my home page, although this was a conflict with a plugin which I have since deleted. Still, I don't understand why no passwords work for any users, even when copied directly from MYSQL Tables. I noticed all user names had the USER_STATUS: 0, so I tried changing to 1 and 2, but this doesn't work either.

Anyone ever experience anything like this before?

Comment: You don't need to change the user_status field. Make sure when you update the password field in mysql to set the field to MD5. After that try logging into admin panel once again.

Comment: MD5 is pretty easy to crack nowadays, so if it's currently set to something other than MD5 then I wouldn't change it

Comment: @AdamHopkinson Wordpress password field defaults to MD5. What would you suggest setting it to? Just curious.

Comment: Ah, couldn't remember what the default is - but it's possible to configure WP to use blowfish or DES instead of MD5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password hashes stored in the database are salted using keys stored in the `wp-config.php` file - they look something like this:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         '3csTaxp]j7S-OKw3Fw?AUqrcXL^xtSTL7bu)|+k`]rNI1HF.H>[U[!dZb;IW.7#b');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '42/jE7=AgQ_6O<vn>C>WC=nf!I,_>?f:Sl,_}ra;yKEYhQ/|Fb >OM9#/`F~)OK&');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'g8{,Msl9dsUWMH<D:4RVW-|y(Pj^@KT6B1V-j$6j @Ik*cocBsOrGiL ktc`bJ!C');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'S!O.$)XE)h{+b5<Qol`p--%=rw:oE(pJyyB%KU{6pi|__@cY#kX=x-xzMo%b8Hz6');
define('AUTH_SALT',        ')c0K(5ARY)T.o/nl$~:]<kE<o@N[)~vX+Qq0vz~,N(Wz@3`b2M<`zlwIi`R1KTF~');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '>i39S}GP*(N9:zNJRLdz9T:VQXLfC&/MviV{9m?&-mu?9]6JBh+T}qp>BBr]$I!J');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'q&bNo4Xl_]+u--hb(I3prA{Se5(*XF#RY4dr:rJ,,U*i+J5krr~I@jnP6Ka6D<4Q');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'y&V`.vx<1L<:2tJ|-&v:DG+V?B%[?Ke]y/^G|B&)2tLm$r3tz78>-Now33LD|ss#');
```

These will be different for different installs of Wordpress, so the passwords won't unhash to the same values.

To get around this, copy the keys from your previous installation (which will disable any passwords set or changed since).

Comment: Thanks! There is no previous install but I just generated new keys and that seems to have worked :).